# android app/business-logic config

Tags: android, configuration

how does an app developer store app-specific (ie. my server addresses, path endpoints, etc.) global and build variant specific config values in an android app? further, is it possible to have overrides? ie. i want to set a default value in my global.config, but collisions in staging-build-variant.config and prod-build-variant.config should override this, while dev-build-variant.config would simply use the default value.

i've read about SharedPreferences but this seems for storing user input at runtime for later runs, and i've read about people using a class to hold constants, but that doesn't quite fit either as i don't get any benefit of a specific configuration values overriding common ones. there is also a lot of seemingly outdated articles out there which i'm not sure are accurate anymore.

i asked this as a comment in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140539/android-config-file/35527922#comment62945691_35527922) which seems to be close to what i'm looking for, but thought i'd ask as a question for more exposure.

EDIT: maybe i explained this poorly - to clarify, [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755155/android-app-business-logic-config/37755421#comment63067770_37755421).

Answer (score 0):

Justin, it seems that what you whant is a library project. You will have to create a library project with one default configuration. 
Let's say that project is called Core and then it has the following strings.xml:

```
<string name="server_address">htt://path.to.server</string>
```

This way you can create a module (called **app1**) for the project that uses the 'Core' library project. Then you will end with **two** strings.xml file. 
So the strings.xml file from your app module will **override** the strings.xml from the library project. Then you can have:

```
<string name="server_address">htt://app1.path.to.server</string>
```

Resources: 
[Create a library Project](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html)

[**UPDATED**]

Instead of use a library you can try a grade variable. See this question:
[Gradle Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197636/is-it-possible-to-declare-a-variable-in-gradle-usable-in-java)
And this link about build variants:
[Build variants](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html)

Comment: this seems unnecessarily complicated. to clarify, an example of a build variant specific config value: api host address. in the production build variant (that i distribute to users, perhaps in something called `production_config.yaml`) i'd want to use `api_host: https://api.mysite.com`.  in a dev build variant (that i develop on and build locally, perhaps in `dev_config.yaml`) i might want to use `api_host: http://localhost:8080`.

example of a global config value (perhaps in `config.yaml`): the path to a user resource (`/users`).

Comment: so in code, doing `Config.get('api_host') + Config.get('users_path')` would return `https://api.mysite.com/users` in a production build and `http://localhost:8080/users` on a dev build.

Comment: Justin, I found a better way by using Gradle Variables. Check the updated answer.