# "Unresolved reference" Cannot access properties file in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, resources

I was following this thread: [Android Config File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140539/android-config-file), to create an config.properties file, from which I could read. Now I have a raw folder and in it a config.properties file that I am trying to access:
res
--> raw
----> config.properties

```
import android.R
import android.content.Context
import android.content.res.Resources
import java.io.InputStream
import java.util.*

class ConfigurationManager(context: Context){
    init {
        val resources: Resources = context.resources
        val rawResource: InputStream = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.config) //this doesn't work
    
        val properties = Properties()
        properties.load(rawResource)
    }
}
```

But I get an "Unresolved reference: config" Error

[image: Unresolved reference: config]

Why doesn't this compile and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove:

```kotlin
import android.R
```

That is importing the *framework's* `R` class. You want the one that is code-generated for your own app, from your own resources.